# Facebook fan detection outside facebook

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-page

During the past few hours I've been working on a "web app" for our hostesses. Its purpose is to login a facebook user and send him to next page where are like boxes with sign out button. This part is done, however I would like to make the process faster by inserting a likejacking script, so the user doesn't have to do anything but to log in and log out.

But I have one problem - how to check if the user is Fan or not (because if he already liked the page he will unlike it)? I've tried a solution which I'm using on my FB pages to fan gate, but it is not working outside facebook.

Here is the code I was trying to use:

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '0000000',
    'secret' => '1654adadadada',
    'cookie' => true
));

?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<?php
    $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

    if ($signed_request['page']['liked']) 
    {
        echo header('Location: liked.html');
    }
    else
    {
        echo header('Location: notliked.html');
    }
```

Comment: Likejacking isn't really a good idea, even if you have a user's permission; it's against Facebook's ToS.

Comment: I know, but it will let them work faster.

Answer (score 2):

your can get the data from FB graph.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/PAGE_ID_TO_CHECK?access_token=XYZ
```

you will not be able to get this data without the token.